# QListWidget::setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed) not working

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

From the book I'm reading:

> By default, QListWidget is read-only. If we wanted the user to edit
>   the items, we could set the view's edit triggers using
>   QAbstractItemView::setEditTriggers(); for example, a setting of
>   QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed means that the user can begin editing
>   an item just by starting to type.

So, I call the function in my code:

```
ui->listWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed);
```

But when I select an item and start typing, nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that the items themselves also have an *editable* flag, so after adding them I had to iterate all of them and set it. Now it's working.

```
// set the editable flag for each item
for (int ii = 0; ii < ui->listWidget->count(); ii++) {
    ui->listWidget->item(ii)->setFlags(ui->listWidget->item(ii)->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
}
// set the editable triggers for the list widget
ui->listWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed);
```

Comment: If we are in `QTreeView`, `self.model.setReadOnly(False)` can solve this problem. It is struck me long time, make a note here.